# Is there a PNG file that exists in almost all Linux distributions?

Tags: linux, images

I need a default image for the demo, but I don't want to attach an extra image to the installation package.

So I want a PNG file that is normally found in almost all Linux distributions, except for Gentoo, of course.

---

addition: under X/Wayland enviroment.

addition: If I only care about gnome, Can I find one? such just as "/usr/share/icons/gnome/256x256/apps/gnome-help.png".

Comment: What do you mean by "the demo" ? Installation package of what ?

Comment: May I suggest two alternatives? 1. Pack a highly compressed PNG. If you play to the compression algorithm, you can get very large (#Pixels) images in a small filesize. 2. Generate an image for the demo. You would prepare and pack a header in the package and then generate the chunks for the image when first executing the demo - randomly or by some clever method you can come up with (need to generate CRC per chunk). (Or maybe more-conveniently-to-generate-from-scratch formats like netpbm or SVG are supported too?)

Comment: Since there is not a image file, I have taken a similar approach. I have produced a simplest PNG file from an SVG file. Cann't use SVG files directly, this will need 'librsvg' dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn’t, not even for common setups of popular desktop distributions.

A basic installation of many distributions might not even have *any* PNG files at all, or at best, the distribution’s logo (`/usr/share/pixmaps/debian-logo.png` on Debian, for example). Servers typically don’t have any desktop environment, and on systems with a desktop, the default selection of PNG files is liable to vary depending on the exact desktop environment (KDE, GNOME, Xfce, ...) and version.

If you only care about GNOME, you could use `/usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/actions/help-about.png`, assuming the GNOME icon theme is installed. This will save you 2978 bytes.

In all likelihood it will be easier to include a PNG file with your demo.

Comment: I just want reduce the package size. :)

Answer (score 0):

- The real answer:

It doesn't exist unless you define "almost all" as "multiple popular desktop distributions"

- The answer you want to hear:

Something like `/usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default16.png` seems like a possibility . (The `chrome` part in the name has nothing to do with the Chrome browser).

For obvious reasons it will only exist on systems with Firefox installed by default. This is the case for "all the "popular ones". The exact contents of this file might be different based on the version of firefox...

- The best answer if you have all the distros you are interested in already installed.

  - Run `bash find / -iname '*.png' -exec md5sum {} \; > pnglist` on every system.
  - Copy all files to 1 system with names like `pnglist1`, `pnglist2`, ...
  - Use perl to compare the files depending on what you actually want (same contents: use regexps on the checksum, same location: use regexps on the path, same name: use regexps on the end of the path, ...)

Comment: Guess what, Debian setups don’t have `/usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default16.png`...

Comment: That would *strongly* surprise me. It's nowhere on the whole filesystem, or it's not in that exact location ?

Comment: It’s `/usr/share/firefox-esr/browser/chrome/icons/default/default16.png`. My point is really that you can’t even rely on common applications’ files being in the same location across distributions.

Comment: This is why i mentioned "the real answer". If you could, it would extremely limit the possibility of the devs behind the distributions.

Comment: Not found in Fedora/RHEL/most RPM based distros.

Comment: Yup, on Fedora it’s `/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default16.png` on 64-bit systems.